# On approximating the distribution of the distance between two random points on an $n$-sphere

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions

Let $\tau\in(0,2)$ a given threshold value. What is the probability that the Euclidean distance $D$ between two points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ selected uniformly at random on the $n$-sphere $\mathcal{S}_n=\{\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|\mathbf{v}\|_2=1\}$, is greater than or equal to $\tau$?

---

It is well known that the probability density function of the Euclidean distance $d$ between two points on the $n$-sphere
$\mathcal{S}_n=\{\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|\mathbf{v}\|_2=1\}$ is

$$f(d)=\frac{\Gamma(n/2) d^{n-2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma((n-1)/2)}\left(1-\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2\right)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}~.$$

It is also well known that, as $n$ increases, $f(d)$ approaches the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}\left(\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{2n}\right)$.

However, even with this knowledge, it is not clear to me how to obtain an analytical expression of $\Pr(d\ge\tau)$ for a finite number of dimensions $n\gg 1$, because it seems hard to evaluate the corresponding integral. Hence, I want to find an approximation of $\Pr(d\ge\tau)$. More precisely I want to obtain a meaningful upper bound of $\Pr(d\ge\tau)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? Please edit your attempts at answering the question and relevant context into the question body.

Comment: @VarunVejalla OK, now I edit the question.

Comment: I apologize if I'm missing something, but isn't the integral polynomial in $d$ so it can be integrated explicitly? If you want asymptotics in $n$ you can look up asymptotics for the gamma function.

Comment: @user293794 , integrating from $\tau$ to $2$ that expression $x^{n-2}(1-(x/2)^2)^{(n-3)/2}$, I obtain a formula depending on the Gamma function and the Hypergeometric $_2F_1$. I would like to find "clean" and "manageable" upper bound for $n\gg 1$ (finite, not an asymptotic result if possible)-

Comment: My apologies I didn't notice the fractional power, but to deal with it you can use the Taylor series for $(1-(x/2)^2)^{(n-3)/2}$ to get a polynomial upperbound since it alternates. The resultant expression can be integrated manually.

Comment: Thank you @user293794, it sounds a simple an effective solution

Comment: I'm happy to work out details if this gives you trouble just let me know

Comment: Thank you @user293794 , I will keep you posted !

Answer (score 0):

Given the normal distribution approximation, wouldn't it just be $\rm{erfc}(\frac{\tau-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2/2n}})/2$ if $\tau>\sqrt{2}$, and $1-\rm{erfc}(\frac{\tau-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2/2n}})/2$ otherwise?

Comment: Thank you, perhaps my edit about the Normal distribution is misleading: I would like to find "clean" and "manageable" upper bound for $n\gg 1$ ($n$ finite, not an asymptotic result).